# SOAP <Body> ...stream... </Body>

Tags: wcf, soap

I'm working on creating a REST service that contacts a SOAP service that already exists. I'm trying to figure out what a certain SOAP response is sending back, but when I log the raw xml it is saying the body is simple ...stream... Does this mean a stream is being passed back or the actual string "...stream..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual stream is being sent, not the string "...stream...". Since many streams can only be read once, WCF won't consume it to log the message, otherwise it would not be able to send it to the other party (or in the incoming message case, to deliver it to the application)

Comment: I'm going to ask this in another question, but I was wondering if you knew how I would go about reading this stream?

Comment: Answered in the other question.